# ui.router/angular - load secondary view with click without replacing main view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am very new to `ui.router`, I just picked it up this morning! But I have a situation where I need to load a first view, and then content within it can be clicked which can be loaded into a second view **without** replacing the content in the first... I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this kind of behavior, though... It seems like it should be simple.

Is such behavior possible?

## HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><!-- menu --></div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div ui-view="main"></div>
        <div ui-view="lookup"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Routing

```
$stateProvider
    .state('pages', {
        url: '/pages/{page:.*}',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
                    return String.format('home/{0}/{1}.html', './pages', stateParams.page);
                }   
            }
        }

    })
    .state('lookup', {
        url: '/lookup/{page:.*}',
        views: {
            'lookup': {
                templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                    return String.format('home/lookup/{0}.html', stateParams.page);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: do you want the second view to be loaded inside the first view?

Comment: If that is the only option, that is acceptable - but I would prefer to just be able to load the two views independently whether they were contained or not. But I'm not super picky about it.

Comment: how does it work right now? I think it should work with what you have. Have tried absolute names, like: `lookup@lookup`,  `main@pages`?

Comment: I am not familiar with absolute names or how to use them. I just know that if I load it up and I open a view in `main`, when I click a link that should open in `lookup`, it opens - but it replaces the URL in the browser, which causes the route to change, which causes the view in `main` to go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('pages', {
        url: '/pages/{page:.*}',
        views: {
            'main': {
                // Showing off how you could return a promise from templateProvider
                templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
                    return String.format('home/{0}/{1}.html', './pages', stateParams.page);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .state('pages.lookup', {
        url: 'lookup',
        views: {
            'lookup': {
                // Showing off how you could return a promise from templateProvider
                templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                    return String.format('home/lookup/{0}.html', stateParams.page);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

url for lookup is now `pages/{page}/lookup`

And your `ui-view=lookup` <del>should</del> may be located inside the views that load inside `main`.
It should work also with your current html set up.

Comment: hrnm, that doesn't seem to work. Here, I made a repository to show you everything if it helps: https://github.com/ciel/router-docs

Comment: thank you so much. routing makes my head spin. I'm unsure why.

Comment: hrnm. It still doesn't work for me. I try clicking on the links inside a page and it just does nothing. Did I not merge the request correctly, or something?

Comment: no, I forgot to change the links sorry , instead of href you have to have `ui-sref`

Comment: If you go to `http://localhost:631/#/pages/beta/0/0` and click on `sigma[0]`, then the text from `/home/lookup/sigma/0.html` should appear beneath it, but nothing happens. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `ui-sref`? I'm trying that out too, though I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the right place. It's telling me ... _Could not resolve '/lookup/sigma/0' from state 'pages'_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96653/discussion-between-koox00-and-ciel).

Comment: Well, we got the behavior to work even if it has bugs, so I'll open a new topic for the new bug. Thank you so much for your help, again. I'll link the new topic when it is made!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035388/ui-router-stop-state-from-triggering-twice-when-using-nested-states

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for your second view. It will allow you to have two templates in the same view.
`params_you_want_to_pass` allows you to get some infos in your 2nd template.

I hope this is clear enough.

## HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><!-- menu --></div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div ui-view="main"></div>
        <lookup-directive info="params_you_want_to_pass"></lookup-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

## ROUTING

```
$stateProvider
    .state('pages', {
        url: '/pages/{page:.*}',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
                    return String.format('home/{0}/{1}.html', './pages', stateParams.page);
                }   
            }
        }

    })
```

## DIRECTIVE

```
angular.module('yourModule').directive('lookupDirective', lookupDirective);
lookupDirective.$inject = [];

function lookupDirective() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: { 
      info: '=' 
    }, 
    templateUrl: 'yourtemplate.html' 
  }; 
});
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on why you say that. Can you elaborate on how a directive solves this?

Comment: Sorry I added an example, is it what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can implement multiple view at same template.

```
<body ng-app="main">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('main', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/header.html'
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/content.html'
                }
            }
        });
    }]);
    </script>
    <a ui-sref="home">home</a>
    <div ui-view="header">header</div>
    <div ui-view="content">content</div>
    <div ui-view="bottom">footer</div>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js">
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I'm trying - it only works if you're loading two views simultaneously. I need to load one, then the next one loads when something else is clicked.

Comment: Why dont you use ng-if condition to hide the template and show  when something is clicked ..

Comment: I don't think you understand the question I'm asking, I am sorry.